# php trouble with array key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple but I'm trying to convert a feed into a nice clean associative array to reference in my views.

Here is the loop (with some text formatting to split them):

```
$headers = get_headers('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sg-retail/' . $file);
        $metas = [];

foreach($headers as $meta) {
            $metaKey = strtok($meta, ':');
            $metaVal = ltrim(strstr($meta, ':'), ':');
            array_push($metas, [$metaKey => $metaVal]);
        }
```

I get this result:

```
[{"HTTP\/1.1 200 OK":""},{"x-amz-id-2":" sNsiGT+p8eZaFJ3RxHKLe\/vN4BfJ27Zp6baI+OvXr+9VqSosNfpSfj73b0XnQAEXKsNgTzBSaM4="},{"x-amz-request-id":" 50EE32CE562BDBE1"},{"Date":" Thu, 14 Apr 2016 23:15:03 GMT"},{"x-amz-meta-featured":" Featured Style: DR349"},{"x-amz-meta-postcopy":" Choose a ring as unique as the woman wearing it, with help from @SimonGJewelry!"},{"x-amz-meta-title":" Friday, April 1"},{"x-amz-meta-hashtags":" #Ring #Jewelry #JewelryGram #EngagementRing #Style #Diamonds #HeAsked #SheSaidYes #Love #Wedding #WeddingInspo #SimonG #SimonGJewelry"},{"Last-Modified":" Thu, 14 Apr 2016 18:55:03 GMT"},{"ETag":" \"7042f7d9383e180d9ed8516d2df0428f\""},{"Accept-Ranges":" bytes"},{"Content-Type":" image\/jpeg"},{"Content-Length":" 499591"},{"Server":" AmazonS3"},{"Connection":" close"}]
```

Which seems fine to me but either I'm retarded or I didn't format these nested arrays correctly.

This works:

```
 return $twitter_posts[0]["metas"];
```

When I try to get a specific variable by the key:

```
 return $twitter_posts[0]["metas"]["x-amz-meta-postcopy"];
```

It teels me to %&$( off:

```
undefined index
```

EDIT: the entire function per request (maybe not relevant but here you go):

function call:

```
$twitter_posts = \App\Asset::fetch('toolkit/social-media/twitter/post-images/');
```

function:

```
public static function fetch($path)
{
    $files = Storage::files($path);
    $data = [];

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $headers = get_headers('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sg-retail/' . $file);
        $metas = [];

        foreach($headers as $meta) {
            $metaKey = strtok($meta, ':');
            $metaVal = ltrim(strstr($meta, ':'), ':');
            array_push($metas, [$metaKey => $metaVal]);
        }           

        $array = ['image' => 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sg-retail/' . $file, 'metas' => $metas];
        array_push($data, $array);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

this call:

```
return var_dump($twitter_posts[0]["metas"]);
```

gets this result:

```
array(15) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-id-2"]=>
        string(77) " cJgthWyhsfIdX5zgNAmS6fp05iYv7gKt4dhThGtItV5QPv5MgLxYsRCfQ8uEwwuWmsSTWSULE5c="
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-request-id"]=>
        string(17) " 2C043CB5EDF8F423"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Date"]=>
        string(30) " Thu, 14 Apr 2016 23:33:38 GMT"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-meta-featured"]=>
        string(22) " Featured Style: DR349"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-meta-postcopy"]=>
        string(80) " Choose a ring as unique as the woman wearing it, with help from @SimonGJewelry!"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-meta-title"]=>
        string(16) " Friday, April 1"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(1) {
        ["x-amz-meta-hashtags"]=>
        string(134) " #Ring #Jewelry #JewelryGram #EngagementRing #Style #Diamonds #HeAsked #SheSaidYes #Love #Wedding #WeddingInspo #SimonG #SimonGJewelry"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Last-Modified"]=>
        string(30) " Thu, 14 Apr 2016 18:55:03 GMT"
      }
      [9]=>
      array(1) {
        ["ETag"]=>
        string(35) " "7042f7d9383e180d9ed8516d2df0428f""
      }
      [10]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Accept-Ranges"]=>
        string(6) " bytes"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Content-Type"]=>
        string(11) " image/jpeg"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Content-Length"]=>
        string(7) " 499591"
      }
      [13]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Server"]=>
        string(9) " AmazonS3"
      }
      [14]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Connection"]=>
        string(6) " close"
      }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see more code here... Is the first code block inside a function? Can we see the function call?  Looks like you have an array called $metas, and then suddenly another one called $twitter_posts. How did you get there?

Comment: `return $twitter_posts[0]['metas']`?? Where's this coming from?

Comment: @larsAnders ok i added the whole function. It's a method to parse S3 object metadata into an array along with the object's url for a laravel application

Comment: @Marcus not so much the issue but there you go

Comment: Can you post the exact `var_dump` of returned data? Your above result is not an array, it is a JSON string. It can not be the result of `array_push`.

Comment: Perhaps not, but having a random return call on an array that is not in your (now former) code makes matters a little confusing. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Marcus absolutely. Just stuck in my own problem now I tend to babble when that happens.

Comment: That big chunk of header data - is this the raw `$result` from calling `get_headers()`. Isn't this just json?

Comment: @DarraghEnright maybe, but I'm parsing them into an array per that model function unless I'm missing something

Comment: It's json alright - you are best advised to use `json_decode()` to parse to a PHP data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays are nested one level too deep. Instead of array_push, you can use `$array[$key]` syntax to get the format you want, so instead of this:

```
array_push($metas, [$metaKey => $metaVal]);
```

you can do this:

```
$metas[$metaKey] = $metaVal;
```

Comment: BOOM! we have a winner, thank you. Knew it was something like that

Comment: No problem.  Do note the comments above about using json_decode() to parse JSON.